# convert pbm -> tiff -> tiffcp -> tiff2pdf . Getting 5mm page

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, tiff, multipage

I usually scan multi-page files, and I'm using an easy way.

```
for f in ???\.pbm; do 
   convert -compress Group4 $f ${f%pbm}tiff; 
done;

tiffcp *\.tiff o.tiff; 

tiff2pdf o.tiff -o o.pdf
```

But this way I can get good TIFF and really bad PDF.

Here are outputs of `identify`:
(similar for each page)

```
Image: o.tiff
Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 1248x1649+0+0
Resolution: 72x72
Print size: 17.3333x22.9028

Image: o.pdf
Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 17x23+0+0
Resolution: 72x72
Print size: 0.236111x0.319444
```

I tried to use density settings on all steps, but nothing helped me. Anybody knows where the mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `tiff2pdf` step, try to use this command:

```
 tiff2pdf  -p A4  -F  -o o.pdf  o.tiff
```

- **`-p A4`**: Force the PDF to use ISO A4 page size (you can also use `letter` or `legal`).
- **`-F`**: Force TIFF to fill the page completely.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! My tiff2pdf doesn't know option **-F**. There is **-f** , but it is for "Fit window" property, and all I get is very small image in center of A4. I can get better image (very close to original) setting resolution to ~5, but that's not true way, is it? `tiff2pdf -p A4 -r o -x 5 -y 5 -f -o o.pdf o.tiff`

Comment: @morodeer: My tiff2pdf came as part of LibTIFF v. 3.9.5. Which version is yours? (Maybe you should update?)

Comment: strange, I have LibTIFF v. 3.9.4-2 , but don't have any option to update it. I'll look into this, thanks =)

Comment: well, that's great. On maverick 3.9.4 is latest, and when I try to remove it, I see a list of 150 dependended programs, which should be deleted to remove libtiff4. Neither can I make install from source until deleting previous version...

Comment: Maverick is 2 years old... Maybe you can build a privat version from source that installs to `/usr/local/..` or event to `$HOME/local/...` ?